# Should I close cursor gotten from adapter?

Tags: java, android, memory, pass-by-value

If I have a SimpleCursorAdapter and I call getCursor() on my instantiated adapter, should I then close this cursor when I'm finished with it, since java is pass-by-value?

Simple example:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(.....);
myListView.setAdapter(adapter);

Cursor cursor = adapter.getCursor();
cursor.moveToFirst();
int id = cursor.getInt(0);
...?
```

If I close the cursor here, will it be closed for the adapter or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have a SimpleCursorAdapter and I call getCursor() on my instantiated adapter, should I then close this cursor when I'm finished with it, since java is pass-by-value?

As you said, the Adapter is still using the Cursor, so no, you should not close it. You should only close the Cursor when you are *completely* finished working with it.

Comment: My question is more regarding if the cursor returned points to the same cursor as the adapter uses, because of pass-by-value.
But I guess pass-by-value doesn't apply for getting properties?

Comment: Yes, it is the same Cursor. You can always save a local reference on the Cursor you pass to `new SimpleCursorAdapter()` and test `cursor == adapter.getCursor()`.

Comment: As a note, be careful with how you use `==` in Java... Only use it to compare primitive objects (not including Strings) and _instances_ (like above). If this is new to you read [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1267661) for a detailed explanation on `==` and `equals()`.